# Qualtrics binding my own code to form input

Tags: jquery, forms, data-binding, binding, qualtrics

I can not for the life of me figure out why this isnt working.

I had to manually add a calpicker. the problem I have is once you hit the submit button it isnt binding. I have spent way too much time on this and need help.

html:

```
            <body>
              <label id="datepickerLabel" for="datepicker">Date (mm/dd/yyyy):</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="val">

              <input id="NextButton" class="NextButton Button" title="Submit" name="NextButton" value="Submit" type="button">
            </body>
```

JS:

```
            $(function (){
              var a = $('#datepicker').val();
              $("#NextButton").bind("click", a, function(){
                console.log("completed");
              });  
            })
```

There is more JS obv but this should give an idea

Comment: What is "it" in the phrase "once you hit the submit button it isnt binding"? Is that the input text from the id="datepicker" input or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the way Qualtrics controls next button click events, is at best difficult to overwrite. Binding to next button click is more difficult than it is worth. you are better off generating a new button, styling it to match, hiding the old button and binding your code to the new button, calling a next button click once it is finished.